# Найти себе пару

Tags: грамотная-речь

Задумался над вопросом: а как можно найти себе пару, чтобы быть вдвоем? А ведь так говорят: "Она нашла себе пару и вышла замуж". Но ведь "пара" - это двое! То есть, по логике вещей получается, что "найти пару" - это найти двух человек, в результате чего получится трое. Например, "два сапога - пара". И правильно говорить что-то вроде "найти себе второго" или "найти кого-то и стать парой"?
Или я не прав?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Он [подходит]ей под пару***. Так говорят в народе. В этой фразе как раз ничего непонятного нет. Найти кого-то, подходящего под пару, то есть похожего. Отсюда, вероятно, происхождение  фразы "найти пару" (найти кого-то под пару себе).

Под пару
кому. 1. Разг. Соответствующий другому в каком-л. отношении, по каким-л. качествам. ФСРЯ, 311. 2. Яросл. Вместе, вровень. ЯОС 8, 20.
Большой словарь русских поговорок. — М: Олма Медиа Групп В. М. Мокиенко, Т. Г. Никитина 2007

Под пару кому. Разг. Кто-либо соответствует кому-либо по своим качествам, положению и т. п. — Каков ваш молодой-то барин?… — Смирёнек очень, Федотовна; не под пару нашей-то… ей бы надо муженька посердитее (Писемский. Тюфяк). Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка. — М.: Астрель, АСТ А. И. Фёдоров 2008**

Answer (score 2):

ПАРА

.
6. кому. в функц. сказ. (обычно с отриц.). Разг.
Тот, кто подходит к другому по каким-л. качествам, в каком-л. отношении. Она ему не п.

Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова

Толковые словари, конечно, не берут значения слов "с потолка", они следуют за живой речью. Ну вот, так говорят, и это зафиксировано в словарях. А формальная логика побоку.

Answer (score 1):

Ушаков:

> > ПАРА
> >  1. в знач. сказуемого. Человек, подходящий к другому, могущий составить с ним что–н. целое, общее (устар.). «Кто беден, тот тебе не пара (не годится в мужья).» Грибоедов. «Она девушка простая, невоспитанная и совсем вам не пара.» А.Островский.

"Найти пару", мне кажется, восходит к "найти того, с кем вы станете парой".